# Next.js - How do I use Provider to Wrap Routes and use Context with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I wrote code similar to the following in create-react-app and I want to know the equivalent for next.js. The code below is my attempt at having a global Context that is available to all pages. The Provider wraps the Links. I get no errors. The problem is inside the **about** page the console.log(state) returns undefined when I expect the Context state. How do I fix this?

Thank you.

pages/index.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import {Provider} from './Context';





function Index(){


    return(

        <div>
         <Provider>
          <ul>
             <li><Link href="/"><a>Home</a></Link></li>
             <li><Link href="/about"><a>About</a></Link></li>
          </ul>
          </Provider>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Index;
```

pages/about.js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import {Context} from './Context';
import {useContext} from 'react';



const About= () => {

 const data = useContext(Context);
 console.log(data)

  return (
    <div>


      <p>This is the blog post content.</p>

    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```

pages/Context.js

```
import React, {createContext, useState, useEffect}from 'react';


let Context = createContext();

function Provider(props){

   const initialState = {
        userID: false,
        user:undefined,
        loading: true,
        authenticated:false
    }

    const [state,updateState] = useState(initialState)




  return(

    <Context.Provider value={{
        state:state
    }}>

      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>

  )

}


const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
export {Provider, Consumer, Context}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can move `<Provider>` into a custom `<App>` component which initializes each page.

pages/_app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import {Provider} from './Context';

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return <Provider><Component {...pageProps} /></Provider>
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

More info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Comment: I created _app.js and pasted your code in. The logged state in about.js still undefined. I am not sure what else I am supposed to do.

Comment: Wait...it does not render to the DOM albeit the console log is giving me the state. Do you have any insight ?

Comment: Which part is not rendering exactly?

Comment: will this also work with ssr?
the problem on my side is if I use getServerSideProps on for a view e.g. /dashboard which should get the user state from the context, it works if I get routed to this page after the login, but if I reload (initial page load), the state is empty.

Comment: @Tobi the context isn't saved on the server so each user request will start with an empty state. You'd need to store the user state elsewhere and retrieve it within getServerSideProps.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is you need to have a parent `Provider` anywhere in your tree to consume a context. In your case, you `Provider` is not a parent of `About` component. You need to move your `Provider` to `_app.js` like [this](https://github.com/jasper95/jobhunt/blob/master/pages/_app.js)

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Edward is actual for classic "Pages router". But for newer "App router" you should use another approach. You can implement `app/providers.js` accordance with [this doc](https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs#rendering-third-party-context-providers-in-server-components)