# Next.js + React Context. Not getting past default values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

I have a context that looks like this:

```
const peopleContextDefaultValue = {
  name: null,
  age: null,
  setName: null,
  setAge: null,
};
    ...

  const [name, setNameState] = useState();
  const [age, setAgeState] = useState();

  const setName = (payload) => {
    setNameState(payload);
  };

  const setAge = (payload) => {
    setAgeState(payload);
  };

  const value = {
    name,
    age,
    setName,
    setAge,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <PeopleContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
      </PeopleContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
```

And I'd like to set some default values off my `.env`, after the app loads for the first time. So I put this `useEffect` in `_app.js`:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { setName, setAge } =
    usePeople();

  useEffect(() => {
    const effect = async () => {
      const name = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NAME;
      const age = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AGE;

      if (name) {
        setName(name)
      );
    

      if (age) {
        setAge(age)
      }
     };

    effect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <PeopleProvider>
      <Navbar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </PeopleProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

But, I keep getting this error:

```
setName is not a function
```

The problem seems to be that `setName` is staying with its default value from `peopleContextDefaultValue`, but I don't understand why. Does anyone understand this? Any idea how to fix/approach this?

Thanks a ton in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provider should be at the highest level of any components using its context, you are accessing context state, so you need to wrap `<MyApp />` in it as well:

```
// For a normal React app, but won't work for Nextjs
<PeopleProvider>
  <MyApp />
</PeopleProvider>
```

In case of Nextjs, the highest level component is the `_app.js` file, so above won't work, since there aren't any higher level component than `_app.js`.

So I'd recommend move your current logic from `_app.js` file to `index.js` file, while keeping the provider code, and your existing code should work, otherwise, you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57717676/16648127).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried to move it to `index.js` like you suggested, wrapping the `Home` component (`return ( <PeopleProvider><div><Head>...</Head></div></PeopleProvider>)`) (not letting me use code markup here for some reason). It's still getting the default values though... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a sandbox? I'll take a look

Comment: Thanks! Here's the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-carson-qey26k?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Hi, you didn't keep the code when moving logic: `<PeopleProvider><Navbar /><Component {...pageProps} /></PeopleProvider>` <- this should stay, as it is providing the context for child component, I modified your code to make it more clearer to understand, please [take a look](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-brown-2vb76y)

Comment: Since overriding variable is considered a bad practice, and there's no need to introduce another layer to setState function(unless you have a good reason to do so), like you defined `setNameState` and `setName`, but the setState function is already enough to mutate the `name` state.

Comment: On the createContext() bit, you actually don't have to provide a default value like so: `createContext(defaultValue)`, it will consume the value from here: `<PeopleContext.Provider value={value}>`, you can refer to [documentation on it](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api).

Comment: Checked the code and documentation - makes a lot of sense, thanks! It does work on the sandbox, but I tried to recreate it in my code editor, and now it gives me this error: `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(0 , _contexts_peoplecontext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.usePeople)(...)' as it is undefined.`. It seems like it's not consuming the provider for some reason?

Comment: Well, that seems like related to import error, you can research into it, or open another question, maybe others will take a look. Anyway, seems like you have solved this one, if you can accept my answer and upvote it, it'll be appreciated! As always, encourage other's question or answer by upvote is considered a positive behavior on Stackoverflow. Cheers!

Comment: I can't upvote yet but accepted, thanks again